# type of data type to represent a number

Tags: java

i have a few methods to calculate the largest prime factor of any mumber but it wont compile because it says my input is out of range

```
public class ProjectEuler3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println  (findfactors(600851475143));
    }


    public static float findfactors(long n){
        long[]factors=new long[1000];int nooffactor=0;
        int c =0;
        for( long i=2;i<n;i++){
                if (findPrime(i)){
                factors[c++]=i;
            nooffactor++;}

        }

        return factors[nooffactor-1];


    }
    public static boolean findPrime(float n){

        for(long i=2;i<n;i++){
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Postfix you value with `L` to denote a constant of type `long`:

```
findfactors(600851475143L)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you enter numbers in your code, they are treated as integer values. However, 600851475143 is larger than an integer can hold. Because of this, you have to append an "L" to mark it as long int:

`findfactors(600851475143L)`

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look into the  [BigInteger class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) as you may want to factor even larger numbers